# How do we know that the maximum/minimum is attainable in the definition of viscosity solution?

Tags: probability, semicontinuous-functions, viscosity-solutions

When I was learning the definition of viscosity solution, I had the following confusion：

The definition of viscosity solution in <[Continuous-time stochastic control and optimization with financial applications](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-89500-8)> is as follows:
[image]

**My question:**

How could we know that the maximium of $w^*-\varphi$ is attainable?
We know that $w^*$ is a upper-semicontinuous function, $\varphi\in C^2$, so that $w^*-\varphi$ can attain its maximum on any compact set. But $\mathcal{O}$ is just a open set but not compact set.

**My guess:**

Is it that "the maximium of $w^*-\varphi$" actually means "the local maximium of $w^*-\varphi$"? If it is the case, then we should have this requirement to $\mathcal{O}$:

"For any $x\in \mathcal{O}$, there exists a compact neighborhood $V_x$ of $x$",
which means that, we need $\mathcal{O}$ is Locally Compact. Am I right?

It would be very grateful if you can provide some answers or comments. Thank you!